# PostgreSQL/PostGIS Count number of visits

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I need to count number of times a vehicle visited a place between two dates considering that the maximum visits per day is 1 even if the vehicle visited the place many times in a day.

[image]

here is what i wrote :

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_vehicle, datehour::date as dt, COUNT(id_vehicle) AS times 
FROM history
WHERE datehour between '2017-01-01' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND
      ST_Contains('POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, x4 y4, x1 y1))',ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude))
GROUP BY datehour::date, id_vehicle;
```

The result I need :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
SELECT id_vehicle,  COUNT(DISTINCT datehour::date) AS times 
FROM history
WHERE datehour between '2017-01-01' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND
      ST_Contains('POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, x4 y4, x1 y1))', ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude))
GROUP BY id_vehicle;
```